# what can i do to stay a dynamic list?

Tags: html, css

i was making a page of products and i'm having some difficulty, the text makes the box bigger and then disturbs the rest and looks just like the picture. I thank anyone who can help, as long as loyate remains responsive, that aligns according to the resolution.
thanks

[normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2S0Hp.jpg)
[decreases resolution and changes position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2G2b.jpg)

```
<section class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 boxContent destaques">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
    @foreach ( $produtos as $produto )


            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 boxProduto">
        <!--<a href="{{ route('produto', $produto->id_produto) }}">-->
            <a href="{{ route('produto', $produto->id_produto) }}">
                <div class="col-xs-12 imgProd ">
                    <img  src="{{ $produto->url_imagem }}" class="img-responsive" >
                </div>
            </a>

                <span style=" overflow-wrap: break-word;
    padding: 15px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    margin: center;">
                    {{ $produto->nome }}
                </span>

            <div class="col-md-12 preco">
                    <p>{{ $produto->pvp }}€</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 detalhes">
                DETALHES
            </div></div>
        </div>

@endforeach
<!--</a>-->
</section>


<style>
    .boxProduto {
        padding: 0px !important;
        margin: 10px 1%;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 2px ;display: block;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .destaques {

    h1 {
        width: 60%;
    }

    .hr {
        width: 21%;
    }


    .boxContent {
        padding: 15px 25px !important;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        background: white;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 11px #ddd;
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    text-align: center;}

</style>
```

Comment: You are not closing the first `<div class="col-xs-12">` properly. Move the `</div>` before the `@endforeach` to AFTER it. Or remove the first `<div class="col-xs-12">` and the `</div>` before the `@endforeach` since you probably don't need it.

Comment: remains the same, if the text is larger, the blank space is there even if you remove it, or change it :\\

Comment: You should still fix the code in this question, regardless if that didn't fix your issue, since what you are showing us is wrong and you are likely to get answers that tell you to fix that. Edit the question to fix the code. You should also post the rendered HTML and the CSS you have.